# During a moderator election, do primary phase votes continue over to election phase or do they reset?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, votes

I was curious if the votes stay with candidates from the primary phase or if they get reset during the election phase, the final phase, and everyone starts fresh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the primary votes are only used to whittle down the (potentially huge) list of candidates down to a more manageable level.

Once the top 10 go through the voting starts again (but picking the 3 preferred candidates in order of preference). That final stage is all anonymous so you won't see who has what vote count until the successful candidates are announced.